# How to dispatch an action in retryWhen of ajax request in epic function [redux-observable middleware]

Tags: redux-observable

How to dispatch an action and wait for the result in retryWhen? As far as I know, this is not possible, so what are the alternatives? I need to dispatch the "UpdateDependency" action, because it already is handled by an epic and dispatches consequent actions that update the state and trigger other operations. So it's not like having a plain ajax request inside of the retryWhen function.

This is case is applicable, when you need to refresh an id token for example and retry the request.

I cannot use dispatch directly, because its direct usage is deprecated.

This is the pseudo code:

```
someEpic = () => (
  action$.pipe(
    ofType("InitialAction"),
    mergeMap(action => {
      return ajax(url)
        .retryWhen(error$ => error$.flatMap(error => {
           return of({ type: "UpdateDependency" }) // this one is not working
         }))
    }),
    mergeMap(result => of({ type: "InitialActionSuccessful" }))
    catchError(error => of({ type: "InitialActionErrored" }))
  )
)

updateSomething = () => (
  action$.pipe(
    ofType("UpdateDependency"),
    mergeMap(action => {
      return ajax(url)
    }),
    mergeMap(result => of({ type: "UpdateDependencySuccessful" }))
    catchError(error => of({ type: "UpdateDependencyErrored" }))
  )
)
```